# Add turn to timeline with time

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, backend

Hello I have a dynamic timeline, for example:

```
{
  start: '18:00',
  end: '21:00'
}
```

Actually this is working time for user. this user works from 18 to 21.
I have a option to assign turn to him based on his working time.

for example these turns assigned in the past (we have some turns in db);

```
[
{
 id: 1,
 start: '19:00',
 end: '19:40'
},
{
 id:2,
 start: '20:20',
 end: '19:40'
}
]
```

**Note: these turns times are dynamic when it's create.**

Now the problem?

I have an endpoint to add new turn. in the code i should check that new turn start and end times are not have a conflict with other turns. User shouldn't have turns with the same start & end times.

totally because we have turn time 19 until 19:40 and 20:20 until 19:40, we should create new turn in the free times (Note that it should check new turn time period and if it's available it should create)

I don't know how to solve it and need the algorithm.

I'm using NodeJS.

Comment: You really need to provide more information.  Can you give us a small but descriptive input sample and the output you would expect it to generate?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Finallly i solved it, it was hard but sweet :)

Comment: A suggestion, then, would be to write your own answer so that this Q+A is preserved for posterity, ideally one with a snippet that shows it at work.  Not only do you help future users, but others might offer suggestions for improvements you hadn't considered.

Comment: You're right. I'll do it.